# This input textbox is not able to printout

Tags: javascript, html

**I am having difficulty with my "test2".**

My first "test1" is working and printing out how I want it. However, test2 is not displaying any result, nothing.

Simple error I suppose, but I am just confused.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var k = event.keyCode;
            document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = event.keyCode;
            document.body.children.myform.children.test2.value = event.keyCode;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onkeydown="myFunction(event)">
    <form id="myform">
        <center>
            <table>
                <tr><td><br /><br /><br /></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1>Key Code</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="test2" type="text" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p id="test1"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Jsfiddle if it helps:**

https://jsfiddle.net/o935hyzv/

Comment: Some minor issues. Don't use tables for layout, use tables for tabular data. Use CSS for layout. Second, the `<center>` element doesn't exist anymore. Third, your `<html>` element appears to have a quote in it. Ex `<html">`

Comment: Do you want "test2" to display actual input or keycode?

Comment: `document.body.children.myform` doesn't work. Correct is `document.forms.myform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to access form fields like in your example, your input tag has to declare `name` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].children.test2.value = event.keyCode;
</script>
<input id="test2" name="test2" type="text" />
```

Anyway, as you declare ID, I would prefer this JS code:

```
document.getElementById("test2").value = event.keyCode;
```